# Generating the output file through java IO

Tags: java, io

I have developed a java code that reads files from the folder chosen by the user. It displays how many lines of code are in each file, it reads only .java filesonly and final outcome is shown on console , I was thinking that output to be get displayed on console but along with a text file conataing the same information to be get stored on desktop also, please advise how to that and the name of the file that is generated its name is to be based on timestamp lets assume that name of the output file would be 'output06282012' and that text file should contain the same information that is shown on the console , here is my piece of code...

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("C:" + File.separator));
        chooser.setDialogTitle("FILES ALONG WITH LINE NUMBERS");
        chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
        chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
                if (chooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
        {      Map<String, Integer> result = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
             File directory = new File(chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath()); 
             int totalLineCount = 0;
             File[] files = directory.listFiles(new FilenameFilter(){
                  @Override
                  public boolean accept(File directory, String name) {
                      if(name.endsWith(".java"))
                      return true;
                    else
                      return false;              
                  }
                }
   );
              for (File file : files)
            {
                if (file.isFile())
                {    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader(file));
                    int lineCount = 0;
                     try
                    { for (lineCount = 0; scanner.nextLine() != null; lineCount++) ;
                          } catch (NoSuchElementException e)
                    {   result.put(file.getName(), lineCount);
                    totalLineCount += lineCount;  
                                    }


                } }
              System.out.println("*****************************************");
              System.out.println("FILE NAME FOLLOWED BY LOC");
              System.out.println("*****************************************");

            for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : result.entrySet())
            {   System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " ==> " + entry.getValue());
            }
            System.out.println("*****************************************");
            System.out.println("SUM OF FILES SCANNED ==>"+"\t"+result.size()); 
            System.out.println("SUM OF ALL THE LINES ==>"+"\t"+ totalLineCount);

             }     

    }
```

Now the idea in my mind id for this logic

1) construct the file name you want to use

2) open the file for write

3) each time you call a System.out.println(), make a similar call to write the same message to the file

4) when you are all done, make sure you close the file handle.

I have an rough idea something like this

```
try{

 java.util.Date date= new java.util.Date();
 System.out.println(new Timestamp(date.getTime())); 

BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C://Desktop//output"+new Timestamp(date.getTime())+".txt"));

out.write("some information");

out.close; 

}catch(IOException e){
  e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

please advise how to that and the name of the file that is generated its name is to be based on timestamp lets assume that name of the output file would be 'output06282012' and that text file should contain the same information that is shown on the console

Comment: You can use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to construct the date that you want.

Comment: Hi user1464381: I see you're relatively new to SO. Welcome. :-)  A tip for getting good answers is to write succinct and quite explicit questions.  Taking this question as an example, we don't need to know what the program does or why you're writing it.  We just want to know your *specific problem*.  I think you're asking how to create a file name of a specific format - but there's a lot of superfluous information there.

Comment: @GregKopff could you please sow in code as I have done that will clear the understanding, thanks

Comment: And a lot of ugly poorly formatted code. Please put in the effort to post *readable* code if you are asking volunteers to put in the effort to help you.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, this is the only thing you are actually asking:

> Please advise how to that and the name of the file that is generated its name is to be based on timestamp.  Lets assume that name of the output file would be 'output06282012' ...

The simple answer is:

```
    String fileName = "output" + new Date().getTime();
```

You then go on to say:

> .... and that text file should contain the same information that is shown on the console

You've got two choices:

- You can *change* where `System.out` goes to by calling `System.setOut(...)`.  (Check the javadoc for details.)
- You can create a `PrintWriter` or `PrintStream` wrapper for your file stream and write to  that instead of writing to `System.out`.

In my opinion, it is a bad idea to use `System.setOut(...)` unless you've got no choice.  It is a "global action" that affects the entire application.  It is better to pass the writer that you want to use as a parameter ...

---

> could you please sow in code as I have done that will clear the understanding

Sorry, I don't write people's programs for them (unless it is an interesting problem!).  You need to write and debug the code yourself, using the information provided in the relevant javadocs.  You can find the Java documentation online on the Oracle website: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/